# Is it possible to capture application activities within Dynamics CRM (e.g. analytic)

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, microsoft-dynamics

We're currently looking over the benefits of using MS Dynamics CRM, and it's been suggested that we also store website usage data in the system (which sort of makes sense since it relates to a customer interaction)..

Is there a mechanism in CRM to record or capture data such as web visits, duration etc??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Power Web Traffic does this and includes useful dashboards for analyzing the data:

http://www.powerobjects.com/add-on-subscriptions/powerpack/powerwebtraffic/

Power Objects provides a lot of other useful add-ons, as well as good support and price ($1/user/month).

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in solution, but you could simply add the necessary entities and transfer the information from your website to the CRM via the web-service interface.

If you are looking for some existing solution, ClickDimensions would be worth to have a look at: http://www.clickdimensions.com/tour/web-tracking.asp

Comment: We use ClickDimensions and are very happy with it!

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if it store websites visits or not but its worth looking at `ADX Studio`

But you can always configure CRM to log website visits by creating an entity which can keep the information you want.

[ADX Portal](http://www.adxstudio.com/)